# datepicker as custom-calendar using native-web component

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, shadow-dom, custom-element

I wanted to use native web in order to have custom calendar. I created js file and wrote some class that extends HTMLElement. Calendar pops up properly but the problem is that I can't choose a day in the calendar. When I try to  choose a date  It throws this  exception : "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker".

My code looks like this :

```js
class CustomCalendar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');

    wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');

    const calendarInputLabel = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('label'));
    calendarInputLabel.setAttribute('class', 'date-label');

    const iconImg = calendarInputLabel.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    iconImg.setAttribute('class', 'calendarIcon');
    iconImg.src = this.hasAttribute('iconImgSrc') ? this.getAttribute('iconImgSrc') : 'api/theme/img/icons-calendar.png';

    const calendarInput = calendarInputLabel.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    calendarInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    calendarInput.setAttribute('id', this.getAttribute('calendarName'));




    shadowRoot.append(wrapper);


  }
  connectedCallback() {
      $(this.shadowRoot.getElementById('from')).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        ,   duration: "fast"
      });




  }


}


customElements.define('custom-calendar', CustomCalendar);
```

```html
<custom-calendar calendarName="from"> </custom-calendar>
```

please help me. How can I fix this ?

Comment: And why not just a datePicker with the functions you are looking for instead of piggybacking yours on a limited datePicker?

Comment: (this is not your issue, but related) You can't do ``this.hasAttribute('iconImgSrc')`` in the constructor, as your DOM element might not exist yet (when you do ``createElement("custom-calendar")`` OR when your script runs **before** the ``<custom-calendar>`` Element is created in the DOM. **Move** all DOM interactions to the ``connectedCallback``. See: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/